# В отчете чтобы поменялось наименование поля

Tags: java, html

Сперва поменял в messages.ru - значение переменной, и когда нажимаю на кнопку скачать отчет, скачивается отчет со старым значением. Как можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

```
    java 
    public static void downloadReport(Long id){
    if(id != null){
        CardReport cardReport = CardReport.findById(id);
        if(cardReport == null){
            index();
        }

        String lang = Lang.get();

        response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(cardReport.mimeType);

        Logger.debug("__downloadReport lang:=" + lang + ", cardReport:=" + cardReport.id);

        File file = new File(cardReport.filePath+"/"+lang+"_"+cardReport.fileName);
        if(file.exists()){
            Logger.debug("downloading file:=" + lang + "_" + cardReport.fileName);
            renderFile(cardReport.filePath+"/"+lang+"_"+cardReport.fileName, cardReport.fileName);
        }
        else {
            file = new File(cardReport.filePath+"/"+cardReport.fileName);
            if(!file.exists()){
                index();
            }
            Logger.debug("downloading file:=" + cardReport.filePath + "/" + cardReport.fileName);
            renderFile(cardReport.filePath+"/"+cardReport.fileName, cardReport.fileName);
        }
    } else {
        notFound();
    }
}

    _______________________
    messages.ru
    report.npa.comment.text=Текст комментария

    XlsParser.java
    // body htable
    CellStyle borderStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    borderStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    borderStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    borderStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    borderStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    row = spreadSheet.createRow(12);

    String[] htable = {
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.column1"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.create.date"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.comment.section"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.comment.text"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.comment.answer"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.comment.like.count"),
            Messages.getMessage(lang, "report.npa.comment.dislike.count")};

    for(int i=0; i<htable.length; i++){
        cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(htable[i]);
        row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(borderStyle);
        spreadSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    html
    #{if card.cardReport.isPublic}
                    <a href="@{Application.downloadReport(card.cardReport.id)}" class="btn btn-primary" style="color: #ffffff">&{'label.link.download.report'}<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                    #{/if}
```

Comment: как передается новое значение

Comment: Просто в messages.ru написал - report.npa.comment.text=Текст замчечания

Comment: И что это дало?

Comment: Ничего). Как делать?